# How to get textbox value from a textbox inside HTML Table cell using javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a HTML table programmatically using javascript, similar to the code below:

```
function AddRow() {
   var rowcount  = $('#tabBillDet tr').length + 1;
   $('#tabDet tr:last').after("<tr><td><input type='text' id='txtItemCode' style='width:80px' /> </td></tr>");
```

I want to get the values entered in this textboxes.

I tried the following:

```
var tab = $('#tabDet tr');
for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    var group = $(tab[i].cells[0].children[0]).val();
    var ItemCode = $(tab[i].cells[1].children[0]).val();
}
```

I have tried by making the ID unique by giving each textbox a seperate ID depending on the row count.

But this is not working. How can I get those values?

Comment: your for loop is not returning anything. In fact `var group = ..` is redefining itself on each loop iteration

Comment: this is just a sample code.

Comment: ii have removed the other lines

Comment: You should not create a table like that, it creates a lot of inputs with the same ID. If you need it for styling, use a class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning the same ID to multiple elements. IDs are unique, as they identify elements in the DOM uniquely. Instead, make the ID a class:

```
$('#tabDet tr:last').after("<tr><td><input type='text' class='txtItemCode' style='width:80px' /> </td></tr>");
```

And then you can get the values like so:

```
$('#tabDet tr .txtItemCode').each(function(){
   var ItemCode = $(this).val();

   //Do something with ItemCode.
});
```

Comment: but i have changed the IDs for every add. still it doesn't work

Comment: I code I gave you did not suggest changes the IDs to unique ones, it suggested using classes. If you replace the lines above with the code posted by myself or others, then it should work. If you're looking for an example with differing IDs, then please say and I shall add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your var is overwrite at each iteration for the for loop, declare var group and itemcode before as an Array, and just put values in your arrays

```
var tab = $('#tabDet tr');
var group = [], ItemCode= [];
for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
  group.push($(tab[i].cells[0].children[0]).val());
  ItemCode.push($(tab[i].cells[1].children[0]).val());
}
```

but what you want do with this values ? why you don't work with id ?

Comment: i cannot use ID of the control. Because i am changing the ID of textboxes at every row to avoid id conflict. This is because i am adding ajax calender to this html textbox

Comment: Thank u for your code. I tried it and but i got this error "Unable to get value of the property 'val': object is null or undefined"

Comment: that's because tab[i].cells[0].children[0] or tab[i].cells[1].children[0] are wrong selectors, can you use console.log of tab[i] to find yours cells ? or just do a jsfiddle

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#tabBillDet tr').each(function() {
        var ItemCode = $("#txtItemCode", $(this)).val();
     });
```

Comment: i cannot use ID of the control. Because i am changing the ID of textboxes at every row to avoid id conflict. This is because i am adding ajax calender to this html textbox.